# Trouble converting a fractal equation to a Python algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, math, procedural-generation

I'm trying to convert the equation outlined [here](http://www.philica.com/display_observation.php?observation_id=52) into Python code:

```
r = +/- (1+1.414sin(theta)cos(theta)-0.5cos(theta)cos(theta))^(1/6)exp(-0.4714(theta))
```

This is my result (slightly hacked for testing purposes):

```
import random
import pygame
import math
from pygame.locals import *

def random_spiral_pos(maxradius,theta=None):
    "Finds a random position in a spiral galaxy pattern."
    #Get a random angle (in rad). Could do this with a random 
    #variable in the range (0,2*pi), but this i clearer if inefficient
    if theta == None:
        theta=math.radians(random.randint(0,360))

    #Then use a fractal equation to get distance from center as a function
    #of angle
    #Source: http://www.philica.com/display_observation.php?observation_id=52
    r = (1+1.414*math.sin(theta)*math.cos(theta) -0.5*math.cos(theta)*math.cos(theta))**(1/6)*math.exp(-0.4714*theta)

    print(r)

    #R will be in the range 0-1, so we multiply it by
    #the radius of our drawing area
    r=r*maxradius

    #Convert the angle into polar coordinates, give the resultant vector
    #magnitude R (polar coordinates are a direction vector from the 
    #origin), then floor those values so Pygame can use them
    x=math.floor(math.cos(theta)*r)
    y=math.floor(math.sin(theta)*r)

    x=x+maxradius//2
    y=y+maxradius//2
    return (x,y)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600,600))
    clock=pygame.time.Clock()
    pygame.key.set_repeat(25,5)

    #Main loop
    while 1:

        #timing
        clock.tick(60)

        #gfx
        screen.fill((0,0,0))
        screen.lock()
        for t in range (0,360):
            screen.set_at(random_spiral_pos(100,math.radians(t)),(255,255,255))
        screen.unlock()
        pygame.display.flip()
```

However, the result seems to merely be a simple spiral. It's likely that I've just made an error in converting the mathematical function to a Python statement, as the mathematics on display here are some ways beyond my education. Is this the case, and how should it be expressed if so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's at least one mistake here.  You have this:

```
r = (1+1.414*math.sin(theta)*math.cos(theta)*-0.5*math.cos(theta)*math.cos(theta))**(1/6)*math.exp(-0.4714*theta)
```

and, according to the link, it should be this:

```
r = (1+1.414*math.sin(theta)*math.cos(theta) -0.5*math.cos(theta)*math.cos(theta))**(1/6)*math.exp(-0.4714*theta)
```

Also, be careful with expressions like `(1/6)` in *Python*. If you're using *Python2.X*, then this will perform integer division and the result is `0`. To get floating point division as standard, you need to put

```
from __future__ import division
```

at the top of your script.

Comment: Your modification to the code does bring it in line with what the author's suggested graphing tool displays, thanks! I'm using Python 3, but I'll keep that in mind. Unfortunately, I still can't figure out how the equation is supposed to give a "plot of a typical spiral galaxy"...

Comment: In case this helped you please [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Well, the problem isn't solved, since the code isn't doing what I need it to, but I'm pretty sure I'm just completely failing to understand what I'm working with.

Comment: @Schilcote: [I don't see a galaxy either.](http://fooplot.com/plot/j5ld3117ah) Frankly, my suspicion is that any resemblance between that function and actual spiral galaxies exists only within the author's mind.